# Is "Hydrogen Bonding" coordinate covalent bond?

Tags: hydrogen-bond

My textbook says:

> The Oxygen atom of other molecules links to form **coordinate covalent**
> bond with H-atom using lone pair.

Now I am confused. Is H-bonding coordinate covalent bond?

Comment: Please understand that just stating random paragraphs from your textbook will confuse us as well. We need to understand more than you've mentioned in your question. Consider adding a picture of the text that has led you to ask this question. Also give examples of the 'other molecules'. You could be knowing the context of the question but we here on the other side feel like we are searching for a needle in the grass!

Comment: H-bonding happens when a hydrogen attached to a electronegative atom like F,O,N gets **electrostatically attracted** to ( in this case I assume ) oxygen with lone pair.

Comment: Hydrogen-bond is not a coordinate covalent bond. it is an electrostatic attraction. The sentence from your textbook describes the third bond happening around the Oxygen atom in ions like H3O+, which is not a Hydrogen-bond.

Comment: The electrostatically attracted might not be the most clarifying description.

Answer (score 1):

"In a way yes". However, rather than starting from nomenclature to get facts, do the vice versa. Otherwise and again "in a way", they could be seen as permanent dipole-dipole interactions, too.

Hydrogen bonds have energy of about a tenth as compared to covalent bonds. So they are considerably weaker but still stronger than other intermolecular interactions.

Thus, they have a special, energetically intermediate, status that was given a name.

How much one goes into quantum mechanical description (the partially donated lone pair is in a deformed orbital between the X and the H)* or if one stops at considering a pure electrostatical attraction between partial and essentially point-like charges as done in not too advanced courses I do not know in details. I guess it depends on how deep one want to go with the description.

But the experimental facts are as I have described above.

*https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/23746149.2018.1428915 is an example.